# Electron velocity in a conductor

Tags: voltage, power, circuit-design

I have a question : **The electron beam in TV picture carries \$10^{15}\$ electrons per second, determine the voltage needed to accelerate the voltage needed to accelerate the electron beam to 4W**

I need help with verification of what I've done.[image: proposed solution]

Comment: Ok to put you on a better track, would it help if I ask how many Amps \$10^{15}\$ electrons per second is if 1 Amp is 1 coulomb per second and 1 coulomb is 6.24 * \$10^{18}\$ electrons?  Note that current is not a measure of velocity as the actual average velocity also depends on beam width and may not be equal across the width of the beam.  Your question is actually about voltage, so your title could use improvement.

Comment: Note also that the cathode ray tube is evacuated so there is no "conductor" as mentioned in your question title.

Comment: The electron beam is in vacuum.  There's no conductor in the electron beam. In vacuum  electrons get accelerated freely to the velocity which is determined by the voltage and the mass of an electron.

Comment: You seem to have assumed that 1 electron/second = 1A.